# Cannot Get BCC on Mail-Listener

Tags: node.js, email, imap

I'm using `mail-listener4` NodeJS module to receive e-mails.

I can get `subject, from, to, cc` values but there is no `bcc` value in returned Json.

`mail-listener4` module uses `imap` lib and `imap` mention that I should be able to get `bcc`.

**imap documentation:**

https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap

The code:

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener4");
const MailParser = require('mailparser').MailParser;
let parser = new MailParser();

var mailListener = new MailListener({
  username: "****",
  password: "****",
  host: "imap.gmail.com",
  port: 993, // imap port
  tls: true,
  connTimeout: 10000, // Default by node-imap
  authTimeout: 5000, // Default by node-imap,
  debug: console.log, // Or your custom function with only one incoming argument. Default: null
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
  searchFilter: ["UNSEEN"], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved
  markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time
  fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`,
  mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
  attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
  attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } // specify a download directory for attachments
});

mailListener.start(); // start listening

mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
  console.log("imapConnected");
});

mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
  console.log("imapDisconnected");
});

mailListener.on("error", function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){


  console.log('WHOLE MAIL' + JSON.stringify(mail,null, 4))

  try {console.log('- FROM : ' + mail.from[0].address);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('FAILED FROM')
  }
  try {
    console.log('- TO   : ' + mail.to[0].address);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('FAILED TO')
  }
  try {
    console.log('- CC   : ' + mail.cc[0].address);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('FAILED CC')
  }
  try {
    console.log('- BCC  : ' + mail.bcc[0].address);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('FAILED BCC')
  }

  try {
    console.log('  SUBJECT : ' + mail.subject);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('FAILED SUBJECT')
  }

  try {
    console.log('  DATE : ' + Date());
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('FAILED DATE')
  }

  try {
    console.log('  BODY : ' + mail.text);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('FAILED BODY')
  }

});

mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment){
  console.log(attachment.path);
});

// it's possible to access imap object from node-imap library for performing additional actions. E.x.
//mailListener.imap.move(:msguids, :mailboxes, function(){})
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The point of BCC is that it doesn't appear in the message.  Otherwise it wouldn't be blind.  Depending on settings it may show up in your Sent folder, but it won't be on messages you've received, by design.

Comment: Even imap documentation says I should be able to get `bcc`, It make sanse that it's hidden. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If BCC appears in the message you could get it.  Generally it is not placed in the message, except possibly in your Sent folder.  You can always view the message headers in an emaol client to see what's in the message.